# What happened to the Jest reporter that makes an outline?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I used to get a nice outline like

```
  Agent
    ✓ is instantiable (6ms)
    ✓ has instance methods (2ms)
    #addFilter
```

with the command: `jest --expand --no-coverage --no-cache`

But now it just collapses

```
 PASS  test/trivia.integration.test.ts
 PASS  test/antares-protocol.test.ts (5.556s)
```

How can I get this outline form back - a reporter?

Answer (score 1):

The `verbose` flag is now required:

`jest --expand --no-coverage --no-cache --verbose`

Comment: Might be worth to add a version to know as of when this required?